# Spring Boot and buildResponseEntity()

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I'm trying to compile code from [spring-boot-exception-handling](https://github.com/brunocleite/spring-boot-exception-handling/blob/master/src/main/java/com/example/springbootexceptionhandling/RestExceptionHandler.java) and part from `RestExceptionHandler`, which extends `ResponseEntityExceptionHandler`

```
 protected ResponseEntity<Object> handleMissingServletRequestParameter(

    MissingServletRequestParameterException ex, HttpHeaders headers,
    HttpStatus status, WebRequest request) {
    String error = ex.getParameterName() + " parameter is missing";

    return buildResponseEntity(new ApiError(BAD_REQUEST, error, ex));
 }
```

not able to be compiled due missing `buildResponseEntity()` method.

What exactly `buildResponseEntity()` does and is that method part of Spring Boot framework? I'm not able to find any reference to that method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a private method at the end of the `RestExceptionHandler` class you link to:

```
    private ResponseEntity<Object> buildResponseEntity(ApiError apiError) {
        return new ResponseEntity<>(apiError, apiError.getStatus());
    }
```